# AngularJS: issues creating an API request

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

I have a scenario in which I have to deal with a misconfigured server, which only understands a stringified JSON. What works with the server is:

```
    var req = JSON.stringify({id: 0, method: 'getToken', params: ['something', 'password', 'some_more_randomness']});
    $http({
        url: 'http://something.com/API',
        method: 'POST',
        data: req,
        responseType: 'json'
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log('data', data);
    }); // works
```

And I've tried to use $resources to take the hassle out of the picture, and I have something like:

```
var apiService = angular.module('apiService', ['ngResource']);

/**
* apiService Module
*
*/

apiService.factory('API', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://somethng.com/API', {}, {
        getToken: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: JSON.stringify({id: 0, method: 'getToken', params: ['something', 'password', 'some_more_randomness']})
        }
    });
}]);
```

Which doesn't work. The server cannot parse the parameters. I'm afraid I don't have access to the server to allow posting properly to it.

What I'd like to do, is to make the exact request from within the service. Other variations – enclosing JSON.stringify inside [] doesn't help either.

What can be done here?

Comment: Did you try: `JSON.stringify({data: {id: 0, method: 'getToken', params: ['something', 'password', 'some_more_randomness']}})` ?

Comment: @MaximShoustin `params: JSON.stringify({data: {id: 0, method: 'getToken', params: ['something', 'password', 'some_more_randomness']}})` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this, the best way to go here is the following;

instead of

```
API.getToken();
```

We need to pass in the data;

```
API.getToken({}, {id: 0, method: 'getToken', params: ['something', 'pass', 'some_more_randomness']});
```

This is not ideal for my situation, because the whole point of creating a new service was to write a wrapper over the API calls, but yeah, we might need one service to call another, which just does the basic calls.